# white list ip address for admin access

Tags: php

I have an area on my site that I would like to only give access to a few people. My code now only works with one ip address, but I would like to be able to add more.

Here is what I am using:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if($ipaddress == '111.111.111.111') {
//Action for allowed IP Addresses
} else {
//Action for all other IP Addresses
echo 'You are not authorized here.'; 
echo "<br />IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$whitelist = array('111.111.111.111', '111.111.111.112');
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)) {
    //Action for allowed IP Addresses
} else {
    //Action for all other IP Addresses
    echo 'You are not authorized here.'; 
    echo "<br />IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @zerkms thank you works perfectly. i will accept your answer when the limit is up :)

Comment: Is this the best way to check this? What if the remote user is behind a proxy? I suppose the proxy would have to be on the white list, making it a moot point.

Comment: @MrOodles: not the best, but the only. There is no data you can trust more than `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (assuming your webserver is configured to initialize it with the client ip)